# Pandas - By the same ID perform multiple conditions on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a challenge when applying multiple conditions in columns, never did it before and would be appreciated some help,from teh database it is required:

```
      ID               user reception_date   end_date    Status
0  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-30 2022-03-30  Accepted
1  42872    andres@a.com.co     2022-03-01 2022-03-04  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  In Study
3   9999  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  Rejected
```

if the ID is the same, check if in the Status column has the status of "Accepted", once verified this first requirement, check if the "end_date" of "Accepted" is greater or equal to the date of the status "In Study", if this condition is true change the status from "In Study" to "Accepted".

The expected output would be as follows:

```
      ID               user reception_date   end_date    Status
0  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-30 2022-03-30  Accepted
1  42872    andres@a.com.co     2022-03-01 2022-03-04  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  Accepted    
3   9999  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  Rejected
```

I have tried several methods to make comparisons such as `np.where`, `df.loc` and tried using `apply()`, however the results weren't good as I expected, I don't have much knowledge about Pandas and I am still learning, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not so straightforward. You need to perform a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to find the closest forward value per row of interest.

```
# ensure using datetime
df[['reception_date', 'end_date']] = df[['reception_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# boolean masks for selection of InStudy/Accepted
m1 = df['Status'].eq('In Study')
m2 = df['Status'].eq('Accepted')

# finding matching rows
s = pd.merge_asof(df.loc[m1, ['reception_date', 'ID']]
                    .reset_index() # save index, we'll need it later
                    .sort_values(by='reception_date'),
                  df.loc[m2, ['end_date', 'ID', 'Status']]
                    .sort_values(by='end_date'),
                  left_on='reception_date', right_on='end_date',
                  by='ID', direction='forward'
).set_index('index')['Status'].dropna()

# updating values in place
df.update(s)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      ID               user reception_date   end_date    Status
0  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-30 2022-03-30  Accepted
1  42872    andres@a.com.co     2022-03-01 2022-03-04  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  Accepted
3   9999  luaquint@a.com.co     2022-03-07 2022-03-30  Rejected
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, never thought this approach, I will save this for future uses, thanks again, you really saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!

Comment: This worked also extremelly well, different approach compared to the first solution posted, I really appreciate your solution and I'll save it in my notes for future use, thank you very much!